# Hash table in MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

I hash strings with FNV into integers. I store them in a custom hash table in MappedByteBuffer to hopefully improve memory access over the same table in the heap memory and also provide consistent storage of the table to the file if the program breaks. Is it possible that such off-heap MappedByteBuffer outperforms heap based hash table in terms of speed? JDK HashMap was too slow.

Comment: What makes you think a memory mapped file will outperform regular memory? In all likelyhood, it will probably be slower because now the kernel has to read/write from the disk.

Comment: If you're going to do this, consider java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect instead of MappedByteBuffer (unless you actually need to persist the hash table to disk).